# script doesn't work in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have used a content slider in my webpage that works with all the latest versions of Google Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer but for some reason it doesn't work in Safari. This is the piece of code that gives Safari a fit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#featured").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
});
</script>
```

Comment: "*doesn't work*" is ambiguous. What is the specific problem, what do you see in the error console?

Comment: Is it the whole content of the script or is it only a short part? The failure might happen before.